# Eclipse-PDT: Type recognition on autocomplete?

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

So from what I've read you have to define the phpdoc with something like

```
/*
*@var 
*@return SomeClass
*/
```

Do you add that to just before you declare `public class MyClass`?

What about when you are dealing with default classes provided by php?

For example:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','username','password','mysql');

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';
$result=$db->query($sql);


while($row=$result->AUTO_COMPLETE_DOESNT_RECOGNIZE_TYPE){

}
```

How would you go about making eclipse-pdt detect the type of variable returned ($result is mysqli_result class) but pressing `CTRL+SPACE` does not return any suggestions. I expected autocomplete to return all the methods to be used on the mysqli_result class (ex. `fetch_object()`).

Answer (score 0):

In a method you should use

```
/* @var $result mysqli_result */
$result = $db->query($sql);
```

If you have an instance variable you should use

```
/**
 * @var mysqli_result
 */
private $result;
```

Please note that if you change formatting of the comment or add/remove asterisks it won't work.

PS: I'm using eclipse Juno.